# Unable to remove decimal from number in Number Column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I have a number column in a sharepoint list with the following settings in place (see screen shot). I need to only see a whole number but a decimal still displays even though 0 is selected for decimal places. Is it possible to remove the decimal from the number?

Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

After my tests, only integers will be displayed after selecting 0 for decimal places.

You can try the following to see if that solves the problem:

1. You could try to clear browser cache then restart it.
2. Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.
3. Whether all SharePoint lists have the same problem? You could create a new number column in another SharePoint list to check.

Comment: Already attempted all things you listed and still no luck. I was just wondering if there was another way... I researched and tried what I could find online but no luck. :(

Comment: Does this happen only in one list, or does this happen to all lists?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Xyza_MSFT

I tried creating and re-creating a new list to see if it was the original list I initially made that had issues but still no luck in removal of the decimal. I tried calculated fields etc., I guess OOTB you get what you get? Or are there any other option to remove decimals?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with decimals not going away. I fixed it by right clicking on edit for that column then chose "more options" dropdown then I clicked "No" on the "Use thousands separator" toggle and the decimals finally went away. Just remember to also choose "0" for number of decimal places as well.